# How do I do a redirect to WordPress permalink with post id via htaccess?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, apache, shortlink

Years ago I saw Jeff Starr of Perishable Press set up shortlinks for a book of his where URLs such as **example.com/u/123** redirected to **example.com?p=123**. I thought that was a handy way to set up no-hassle shortlinks using the WordPress post id.

I can't find the snippet back and I'm not good with htaccess. Here's a relevant snippet I found that I'm trying, but it's returning 404s. Is this on the right track, how would you fix it?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^go/(\d+)$ /?p=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Sorry about the previous answer. What I said about the 404 is true.. except, I didn't realize I hadn't actually saved the updated `.htaccess` file. :p I've revised the answer and I hope it's still helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure why that `RewriteRule` returned a 404 error for you, because I've tested it and it did work as expected — if permalinks are actually enabled, you would be redirected to the actual post permalink.

And here's the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^go/(\d+)$ /?p=$1 [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I.e. I put the custom rewrite rule *above* the WordPress rewrite rules. That way, your custom rules would work and remain even when WordPress permalinks are updated.

Nonetheless, you could also use the `parse_request` to achieve the same results (i.e. redirection):

```
add_action( 'parse_request', function( $wp ){
    if ( preg_match( '#^go/(\d+)$#', $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
        if ( $matches[1] && get_post( $matches[1] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $matches[1] ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}, 0 );
```